# VSS backup acess is denied WinServ2016

Tags: backup, windows-server-2016, vss

On my windows server 2016 I userd disk2vhd for backups, but for some reason last backups that disk2vhd created in last time was invalid.
Disks works ok and whole system too.
So I want to make backups with VSS, I created vss snapshot mounted it as disk S: and tried to copy files from it via
xcopy /E /H /R
robocopy /xj /E /B

But in both ways I got "Access is Denied" on some files, sometime system files, sometime user files.
I am using cmd as administrator.
Admin approval mode disabled in group policy.
But I am still getting "Access is Denied" error

How I can backup full disk without getting Access is Denied error ?
Maybe someone can advice me easier way to do it.

Comment: Just out of interest what do you copy the VHD's to to take them off-site?

Comment: @Chopper3 to save disk backup in another location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why my cmd can't get access.

Workaround that I found is use any other app like total commander, Salamander, 7zipFM,Cygwin with elevated rights and it works ok.

UPD:
Also if you want even more ritghts you can use PsTools

psexec.exe -s -i cmd.exe

and you'll get Local SYSTEM user account rights.

BTW:
on symlinks you'll still get Acess is Denied.